# Как повернуть объект в unity по углу дочернего объекта

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Всем привет, пытаюсь сделать игрока на юнити, и у меня поворачивается голова от мышки, при этом тело должно не поворачивается пока мы не нажали WASD или стрелочки, говоря кароче пытаюсь сделать контроллер как в GTA SA, проблема в том что мне нужен повернуть основной объект player, на угол дочернего объекта head(находится в иерархии костей) но когда я пишу что то по типу угол игрока = угол головы то ничего не происходит, (у меня нету какой то переменной угла, я использую риг для поворота головы в сторону объекта Target)
Я пробовал:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, head.transform.rotation.x, 0))
```